# Assign some of fields from another array based on id and get final output based on value type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, functional-programming

```
arr1 = [ 
         { id : 1,
           name : 'book1',
           description: 'some text'
         },
         { id : 2,
           name : 'book2',
           description: 'some text'
         },
         { id : 3,
           name : 'book3',
           description: 'some text'
         }
       ]

arr2 = [ 
         { id : 1,
           name : 'book1',
           type : 'thriller',
           publisher : 'some x',
           isbn : '2983457928435',
           date : '20-1-2014'
         },
         { id : 2,
           name : 'book2',
           type : 'action',
           publisher : 'some x',
           isbn : '2983457928435',
           date : '20-1-2014'
         },
         { id : 3,
           name : 'book3',
           type : 'thriller',
           publisher : 'some y',
           isbn : '2983457928435',
           date : '20-1-2014'
         }
       ]
```

I want to assign fields 'type' and 'publisher' to arr1 based on id value and in parallel i want the array based on type.

The required output is

```
arr3 = { 
   'thriller': [
     { id: 1, name: 'book1', type: 'thriller', publisher: 'some x', description: 'some text' }, 
     { id: 3, name: 'book3', type: 'thriller', publisher: 'some y', description: 'some text' }
   ], 
   'action': [
     { id: 2, name: 'book2', type: 'action', publisher: 'some x', description: 'some text' }] 
 }
```

Performance is key issue. I can achieve above one using 2 functions but I want to achieve it in single function.

Edit1:- In arr1 along with above fields I am getting some other fields from database(mongodb). For simplicity I have included what ever is necessery.

Currently I am achieving this with below 2 functions

Function 1:-

```
let result = arr1.map((e) => {
        for(let element of arr2){
            if(e.id === element.id)
              { 
                e['type'] = element.type
                e['publisher'] = element.publisher
              }
        }
        return e
      })
```

Function 2:-

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    var key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

let output = groupBy(result, 'type');
```

What I want is combine both functionalities and perform it in single function call.

Comment: Can you provide the two functions that you are using?

Comment: `but I want to achieve it in single function.` why? Invoking functions does not affect performance.

Comment: And why do you need `arr1` at all?

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn and @ Jonas W, Have a look at Edit1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only noticeable performance issues I can imagine you'll encounter appear once you do this:

```
arr1.reduce(function (acc, e) {
  for (let element of arr2) {
    /* ... */
  }
})
```

This nested loops bumps up the iteration count quite a bit. For every element of `arr1`, we loop over (potentially) every element of `arr2`, giving us a number of iterations between `arr1.length` (best case) and `arr1.length * arr2.length` (worst case). If you're working with really big data sets, this difference might be noticeable...

Usually, the solution is to index your arrays in to an object or map, which allow for quicker lookups. Converting the arrays takes some time, but your loop will run faster.

Here's my suggestion in bullets:

1. Convert `arr1` to an index `bookDescriptions` of the form:
   `{ id: { name, id, description } }`
2. Convert `arr2` to an index `bookMetadata` of the form:
   `{id: { name, id, type, publisher } }`
3. Make a list of `books` dat merges these by id in to:
   `[ { name, id, type, description, publisher } ]`
4. Use your `groupBy` to do the final grouping

In code:

```js
// Index an array of values by a unique property
const indexBy = (k, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, { [x[k]]: x }),
  {}
);

// Group an array of objects by a certain property
const groupBy = (k, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, { 
    [x[k]]: acc[x[k]] 
      ? acc[x[k]].concat(x)
      : [x]
  }), 
  {}
);

// Return array without duplicates
const uniques = xs => Array.from(new Set(xs));

// Merge two indexes by their keys using Object.assign
const mergeIndexes = (i1, i2) => 
  uniques([
    ...Object.keys(i1),
    ...Object.keys(i2)
  ]).map(k => Object.assign({}, i1[k], i2[k]));


const bookDescriptions = indexBy("id", getDescriptions());
const bookMetadata = indexBy("id", getMetadata());
const books = mergeIndexes(bookDescriptions, bookMetadata);

const booksByType = groupBy("type", books);

console.log(booksByType);

       
       
function getDescriptions() { return [{id:1,name:"book1",description:"some text"},{id:2,name:"book2",description:"some text"},{id:3,name:"book3",description:"some text"}]; };
function getMetadata() { return [{id:1,name:"book1",type:"thriller",publisher:"some x"},{id:2,name:"book2",type:"action",publisher:"some x"},{id:3,name:"book3",type:"thriller",publisher:"some y"}]; };
```

If this still gives you performance issues, you can think about micro optimizations like merging functions, combining steps, etc. (but I don't expect you'll need to)

*EDIT:* for reference, here's the performance for the indexed approach compared to your nested loop approach for 1000 books. I'm getting a performance improvement of roughly 10x on my machine...

```js
// Index an array of values by a unique property
const indexBy = (k, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, { [x[k]]: x }),
  {}
);

// Group an array of objects by a certain property
const groupBy = (k, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, { 
    [x[k]]: acc[x[k]] 
      ? acc[x[k]].concat(x)
      : [x]
  }), 
  {}
);

// Return array without duplicates
const uniques = xs => Array.from(new Set(xs));

// Merge two indexes by their keys using Object.assign
const bookMerger = (
  { name, id, description},
  { type, publisher }) => (
    { name, id, description, type, publisher }
  );
  
const mergeIndexes = (i1, i2) => 
  uniques([
    ...Object.keys(i1),
    ...Object.keys(i2)
  ]).map(k => bookMerger(i1[k], i2[k]));


console.time("indexed approach");
const bookDescriptions = indexBy("id", getDescriptions());
const bookMetadata = indexBy("id", getMetadata());
const books = mergeIndexes(bookDescriptions, bookMetadata);

const booksByType = groupBy("type", books);
console.timeEnd("indexed approach");

console.time("nested loop approach");
let result = getDescriptions().reduce(function (acc, e) {
  let arr2 = getMetadata();
 for(let element of arr2){
            if(e.id === element.id)
              { 
                e['type'] = element.type
                e['publisher'] = element.publisher
                break
              }
        }
           var key = e['type'];
    if (!acc[key]) {
           acc[key] = [];
            }
          acc[key].push(e);
          return acc;
    
        }, {});
console.timeEnd("nested loop approach");
       
function getDescriptions() { return Array.from(
  Array(1000),
  (_, i) => (
    {id:i, name:"book1", description:"some text"})
  );
}

function getMetadata() { return Array.from(
  Array(1000),
  (_, i) => (
    {id:i,name:"book1",type:"thriller",publisher:"some x"}
  ));
};
```

Comment: I agree with your point of "arr1.length (best case) and arr1.length * arr2.length (worst case)". But in my real case in arr2 along with type and publisher fields I have some other fileds and I don't want them in final output that is way I have to assign type and publisher fields only.

Comment: Can you suggest me some other and better way to omit for loop then if condition? Because I need only type and publisher fields but arr2 consists some other extra fields.

Comment: This function is the current *merge* logic: `k => Object.assign({}, i1[k], i2[k])`. You can manually create a new object instead. For example: `k => ({ id: i1[k].id, type: i2[k].type })`

Comment: In above functionality it has to loop through array to assign and append fields. Is this assumption right? I have tested your code for length of 18 items in arrays and compared calculation time and it is taking some extra time.

Comment: The code I wrote will not be faster for 18 items... I thought you were talking more like 1000 items when you said you were worried about performance ;) Try it for 100, 1000 and 10000 and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: Thank you very much @user3297291. I will opt it in future.

Comment: In my answer if I use findIndex does it reduce number of iterations?

Comment: No. `findIndex` and `indexOf` loop over your data internally. (i.e. they just hide the loop)

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr1 = [ 
         { id : 1,
           name : 'book1',
           description : 'Some text here'
         },
         { id : 2,
           name : 'book2',
           description : 'Some text here'
         },
         { id : 3,
           name : 'book3',
           description : 'Some text here'
         }
       ]

arr2 = [ 
         { id : 1,
           name : 'book1',
           type : 'thriller',
           publisher : 'some x'
         },
         { id : 2,
           name : 'book2',
           type : 'action',
           publisher : 'some x'
         },
         { id : 3,
           name : 'book3',
           type : 'thriller',
           publisher : 'some y'
         }
       ]

let result = arr1.reduce(function (acc, e) {
 for(let element of arr2){
            if(e.id === element.id)
              { 
                e['type'] = element.type
                e['publisher'] = element.publisher
                break
              }
        }
           var key = e['type'];
    if (!acc[key]) {
           acc[key] = [];
            }
          acc[key].push(e);
          return acc;
    
        }, {});
console.log(result)
```

I have ended up with above solution.

Comment: I see you've accepted your own answer, which doesn't include a different approach than the original question. I've added a performance test to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51362694/3297291) to show you that for larger data sets you will start seeing a difference. Let me know if you still think nested loops are your best option.